# Laravel | Javascript | Select specific html table in the blade

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have `javascript` code that selects data in all tables existing in my Laravel blade.

I would like to apply this code only for a specific table with `id="exemple"`. How can I accomplish that?

My javascript code :

```
<script>
  function groupDataByDate() {
    var columns, columnOrder, data,
    table = $('table'), mainObj = {};
    columns = [{
      title: 'date',
      values: [4,9]
    }];

    table.find('tbody tr').each(function() {
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using

```
table = $('table');
```

which targets all `<table>` elements in your HTML, use

```
table = $("#example");
```

To only target an element with `id="example"`.